# Unable to retrieve the data using ID from MongoDB using Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a rest API using NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB. I can successfully create data and view them in the database using MongoDB Compass but can't get single data using Id generated. Whenever I try it gives me a 404 error.

Here is my code:

1. bootcamps.js (controller)

   ```
    const Bootcamp = require('../models/Bootcamp')

    exports.getBootcamps = async (req, res, next) =>
    {
        try {
            const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find()

            res.status(200).json({success: true, count: bootcamps.length, data: bootcamps})
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json({success: false})
        }
    }




    exports.getBootcamp = async (req, res, next) =>
    {
        try {
            const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findById({_id: req.params.id})

            if (!bootcamp)
            {
                return res.status(400).json({success: false})
            }


            res.status(200).json({success: true, data: bootcamp})
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json({success: false})
        }

    }


    exports.createBootcamps = async (req, res, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.create(req.body)

            res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                data: bootcamp,
                msg: 'Bootcamp created'
            })


        } catch (error)
        {
            console.log(error)
           res.status(400).json({success: false})
       }
    }


    exports.updateBootcamp = async (req, res, next) =>
    {
       try {
        const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
            new: true,
            runValidators: true
        });

        if (!bootcamp)
        {
            return res.statuc(400).json({success: false})
        }

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: bootcamp })
       } catch (error) {
        return res.statuc(400).json({success: false})
       }

    }


    exports.deleteBootcamp = async (req, res, next) =>
    {
        try {
            const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

            if (!bootcamp)
            {
                return res.statuc(400).json({success: false})
            }

            res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: {} })
           } catch (error) {
            return res.statuc(400).json({success: false})
           }

    }
   ```
2. Bootcamp.js (model)

   ```
        const mongoose = require('mongoose')


        const BootcampSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a name'],
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [50, 'Name can not be more than 50 characters']
    },
    slug: String,
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a description'],
        maxlength: [500, 'Name can not be more than 50 characters']
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        match: [
            /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/,
            "Please use a valid URL with HTTP or HTTPS"
        ]
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: [20, 'Phone number can not be longer than 20 characters']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        match: [
            /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)+@\w+([\.:]?\w+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/,
            'Please add a valid email address'
        ]
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an address']
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            required: false
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            required: false,
            index: '2dsphere'
        }
    },
    formattedAddress: String,
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipcode: String,
    country: String,
    careers: {
        type: [String],
        required: true,
        enum: [
            'Web Development',
            'Mobile Development',
            'UI/UX',
            'Data Science',
            'Business',
            'Other'
        ]
    },
    averageRating: {
        type: Number,
        min: [1, 'Rating must be at least 1'],
        max: [10, 'Rating can not be more than 10']
    },
    averageCost: Number,
    photo: {
        type: String,
        default: 'no-photo.jpg'
    },
    housing: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    jobAssistance: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    jobGuarantee: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    acceptGi: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
   });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Bootcamp', BootcampSchema)
   ```
3. bootcamps.js (routes)

   ```
    const express = require('express')
    const { getBootcamp, getBootcamps, createBootcamps, updateBootcamp, deleteBootcamp } = require('../controllers/bootcamps')


    const router = express.Router()


    router.route('/').get(getBootcamps).post(createBootcamps)


     router.route(':id').put(updateBootcamp).delete(deleteBootcamp).get(getBootcamp)


    module.exports = router
   ```
4. index.js (entry file)

   ```
    const express = require('express')
    const dotenv = require('dotenv')
    const morgan = require('morgan')
    const connectDB = require('./config/db')
    const colors = require('colors')

    dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })

    connectDB()


    const bootcamps = require('./routes/bootcamps')

    const app = express();


    app.use(express.json())

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    {
        app.use(morgan('dev'))
    }

    app.use('/api/v1/bootcamps', bootcamps)

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000


    const server = app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is running in 
   ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold))


    process.on(`unhandledRejection`, (err, promise) =>
    {
        console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`.red)
        server.close(() => process.exit(1))
    })
   ```

[image: Get all bootcamps - postman]

[image: Get one bootcamp -postman]

Comment: is something wrong with the route. i see a 404 error which you havent defined. also did you define your route as something like `..bootcamps/:id`

Comment: also make sure you have passed the correct controller method in the route

Comment: Hello @cmgchess, I have added my routes and entry files.

Comment: did you try like `/:id`

Answer (score 0):

Found the error!

I forgot to add the '/' on the single route

Before:

```
router.route(':id').put(updateBootcamp).delete(deleteBootcamp).get(getBootcamp)
```

After:

```
router.route('/:id').put(updateBootcamp).delete(deleteBootcamp).get(getBootcamp)
```

Surprisingly the console and postman result didn't complain and point that out!